# Does the Cassandra driver have its own speculative-retry mechanism?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Cassandra since v2.0.2 have mechanism named `Rapid Read Protection` described in details [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/rapid-read-protection-in-cassandra-2-0-2). For this question important notes from blog post are:

1. Mechanism controlled by a per-table `speculative_retry` setting
2. Coordinator node is responsible for applying this mechanism - it starts new read-request if retry condition is satisfied.

But documentation for cassandra java-driver describes something very similar [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/speculative_execution/), named also similar `speculative query execution`. But driver needs some additional libraries to use this feature.

Q1: Am I right that this mean that it is implemented on driver-side and have no relations to Rapid Read Protection implemented inside cassandra?
If so, that means that driver will retry a query with anther coordinator, if driver retry condition is satisfied.

Q2: For read queries retry on coordinator-side seems more effective, since even when you switch coordinator for query it's still a chance that another one will query same set of nodes(and will have same response time as previous). But I didn't find how to enable driver-side retry only for write queries. So if I want to use retry on all type queries - should I disabler RR on cassandra-server-side, since double protection will give more pressure to cluster? Or I can gain some profit by enabling both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, speculative query execution in the driver is completely independent of the cluster rapid reads.

Q2.1: For the first part, it's not absolutely necessary as the coordinator could be busy processing other requests, etc.

Q2.2: I think you can enable both mechanisms (cluster and client side) and play a bit with their configurations.